# Downgrade MariaDB data to earlier version

Tags: mariadb

I recently went from 10.0.21 to 10.1.8 MariaDB. All testing went well but there were some minor pieces that were over looked. So I need to downgrade/migrate data from MariaDB 10.1.8 to 10.0.21. I was thinking I could migrate the data to a fresh install of 10.0.21 but was wondering if MariaDB inserted some extra stuff during a version upgrade.

Is there a true method to Grab the data from an upgraded version of MariaDB and move it to a lower version of MariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqldump to dump the database from the higher and import it into the lower MariaDB version.  This works as it uses SQL statements.

Usage and examples: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqldump/

Backup and Restore Overview ("data can be restored on other […]  MariaDB versions"): https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/backup-and-restore-overview/

Answer (score 0):

You can see the installed version with

```
dpkg -l |grep mariadb-server-10|grep ii|xargs|cut -d" " -f3
```

I have `1:10.3.31-0+deb10u1` installed. To Install an older version replace the number and install with

```
apt install mariadb-server-10.3=1:10.3.25-0+deb10u1 mariadb-server-core-10.3=1:10.3.25-0+deb10u1
```

You should set the version on hold afterwards with

```
apt-mark hold mariadb-server-core-10.3 mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-common
```

Note: Here I run `mariadb-common` in the installed version 10.3.31 and -server in 10.3.25, which works fine